# Designing a monadic type

Tags: haskell, monads, combinators

I'd need some help to design a monadic datatype, I seem to have trouble wrapping my head around the idea, but I pretty definitely know what I want. Only the type checker seems to require some persuading in that matter.

What I want is some datatype `Primitive` that can be a monad. Functions of that are basically drawing primitives, and I want to be able to combine them and the combinations being primitives as well, much like the `Parser` type in the library `parsec`. But the actual drawing has to be done with an `IO` monad.

Incidentally, I also have a class `Drawable a` like this:

```
class Drawable a where
    draw :: (MonadIO m) => Pos -> a -> m ()
```

And I want every Primitive of course to be drawable. Am thankful for any input.

Comment: http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2008/07/18/semantic-design/ addresses this.

Comment: The `draw` method doesn't really make sense to me. I'd instead choose this type signature: `draw :: Pos -> a -> IO ()`. Why would `draw` return anything besides unit...isn't it just an output function?

Comment: @Dan Yeah I just saw it at well. Thanks for pointing it out, copied it without actually looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand why you think this should be a monad. What's monadic about it?

You should design the API you want first, and incrementally think about how to abstract it.

Incidentally, Brent's diagrams library has a very nice compositional API that could provide some good ideas: http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2008/04/30/new-haskell-diagrams-library/

Comment: I took a look at it, and it pretty much resembles my first idea: Create a recursive data type. But I kind of decided against it, because I want the primitives being drawn right away, since a `Primitive` can be drawn several times per second, not only once like in the library. If there is a complex data type made every time it's drawn, that can be quite an overhead.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like the Cairo Haskell API.  Take a look at that.

Comment: I wish you gave that Cairo reference as an answer so I can tick it. Thanks!

Comment: cf http://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphics-drawingcombinators as well.  It's a compositional drawing API (applicative, not monadic) whose type parameter is used for selection (detecting what was clicked on).